# Avoid subshell from pipe on dash

Tags: bash, pipe, ksh, subshell, dash-shell

I have this example code:

```
find "$1" ! -regex "$regex" 2>/dev/null | while read line ; do
    a="$line"
done

echo ("$a") # prints nothing because of subshell
```

I need:

- Workaround for subshell to make `$a` visible outside (in global scope)
- To NOT use bash's process substitution
- To have compatible with dash, bash and korn shell

How can I achieve this? Is there any simple solution?

Comment: @snath03 Can you please add again the bash tag since the OP is asking for a solution that also works on bash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an explicit named pipe.

```
mkfifo named_pipe
find "$1" ! -regex "$regex" 2> /dev/null > named_pipe &

while read line; do
    a=$line
done < named_pipe
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid creating file? We can't make temporary files :S

Comment: Afraid not. Your only other choice is to replace the call to `find` with a shell function (recursive, if you need to descend into subdirectories) that uses a `for` loop to iterate over all the files in the current directory hierarchy. `expr` can be used to check each file agains the regular expression, or you might be able to get away with a filename pattern if the regex isn't too complicated.

Comment: Okay, well, it works perfectly anyway, so marking as solved. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, it is not so much the subshell that is bothering you, but the fact that the variable does not retain its value outside the subshell.
You could use code grouping like this:

```
find "$1" ! -regex "$regex" 2>/dev/null | 
{ 
  while read line
  do
    a=$line
  done
  echo "$a"
}
```

You can use the value of variable `a` as long as it is inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

Without a named pipe and without running the whole thing in a subshell, you can use a [here-doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) with a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) inside the here-doc:

```
while read line; do
    a=$line
done <<EOF
    $(find "$1" ! -regex "$regex" 2>/dev/null)
EOF

echo "$a"
```

This should be portable.

**See also.** [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

**Note.** Parsing the output of `find` like this is an antipattern.

Comment: If you say it's an anti pattern, you have to justify.
We don't know what's the purpose of reading find's output here, so it could be a "legit" usage.

Comment: @JohanBoulé Reading the “raw” output of `find` line by line will break if there are file names with new line characters. If possible, use `-exec` or other predicates to directly process the files; if not possible, use some serialization: GNU `find` has the `-print0` predicate to separate file names with a null character; other `find` can serialize file names with, e.g., `-exec printf '%s\0' {} \;`. Then you will parse these file names with `while IFS= read -d '' line; do a=$line; done < <(find ... -print0)`, or if you want an array: `mapfile -d '' filearray < <(find ... -print0)`.

Comment: the only anti pattern I see was that with the given code the find command is executed first entirely, and only then the current shell starts processing its output. Using process substitution solves the problem of avoiding the subshell creation that the OP asked for, but not in a portable manner. -exec is out of question here for the same reason. Bizarre filenames aren't the topic here. Quite often you know you're in a context where you're getting reasonable, nonevil input.

Comment: @JohanBoulé that's up to you if you _assume_ filenames without newline characters, but then you're deliberately introducing errors in your code.

Comment: @gniouf_gniourf I was trying to keep you focus on the OP! So, there is no other solution than to use command substitution for portable code, which makes the processing sequential. That's unfortunate. Of course FIFO would make it possible too but that's a lot more code to write.